# DIsplaying column name along with column index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want the column index to be displayed along with the column names. Looking at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html#pandas.DataFrame.info) for `df.info()`, using `verbose=True` should help but it isn't.

```
import pandas as pd

records = {'a':['abc','def','ghi'], 'b':[22,41,13], 'c':[133,3123,552]}
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df.info()

Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    3 non-null object
b    3 non-null int64
c    3 non-null int64

df.info(verbose=True)
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    3 non-null object
b    3 non-null int64
c    3 non-null int64
```

I've written a function to do the same.

```
def get_features_with_indices(df):
    for i in range(len(df.columns)):
        print(i,df.columns[i])
        
get_features_with_indices(df)

0 a
1 b
2 c
```

But I'm looking for a better way. Is there a built-in pandas functionality to get this so it can be cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create frame out of column names:

```py
df.columns.to_frame(index=False, name='cols')
```

OUTPUT:

```py
  cols
0    a
1    b
2    c
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `df.columns.to_series(index=range(0,len(df.columns)))` as I did not want a frame.